# How to stop a function from running in React if another function has returned its data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions that are calling two endpoints that pull data from a database. One function sometimes returns data quicker than the other.

```js
// Function One
const getDataOne = async => { 
  await fetch('//some-api/one').then(res => res.json()).then(data => { setDataOne(date) }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

// Function Two
const getDataTwo = async => { 
  await fetch('//some-api/two').then(res => res.json()).then(data => { setDataTwo(date) }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I have both functions written out separately like above and BOTH are fired at the same time via a `onClick` How can I stop the slower function from running if the quicker one has returned its data?

The data is populating tables, and if one table is populated before the other than there is no need to populate the slower table.

I know you can use `return` to exit out of a function, but not sure how we could use that to exit another function if one function has data returned before the other.

Could I do something like? ...

```js
const getSegmentData = async (date, token) => {
    getDataOne(token)

    if (!getDataOne) {
      getDataTwo(date, token)
    }
  }
```

Reason I am not a fan of the above, is because if `getDataOne` takes say 15 seconds...then `getDataTwo` would have to wait for 15 secs before running. Which would increase the users wait time.

#### Actual live code with Promise.Race

```js
const getThirdPartyLiveRampSegments = async (date, token) => {
    // resets setThirdPartyLiveRampSegments
    setThirdPartyLiveRampSegments([])
    setThirdPartyLiveRampSegmentsLoading(true)

    let count = 0

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      count++
      setThirdPartyLiveRampSegmentsCount(count)
    }, 1000)

    if (token) {
      try {
        await fetch(
          `//${
            import.meta.env.VITE_BE_HOST
          }/api/thirdparty-liveramp-segments?date=${date}&token=${token}`,
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            setThirdPartyLiveRampSegments(data)
            setThirdPartyLiveRampSegmentsLoading(false)

            // clears token input to reuse with date input
            setToken('')

            // clear timer
            clearInterval(timer)
          })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    } else {
      setThirdPartyLiveRampSegmentsLoading(false)
      popupValidation('error', 'Please enter a segment id')
    }
  }
  const getportalDboAdvpixel = async token => {
    // resets setportalDboAdvpixel
    setportalDboAdvpixel([])
    setportalDboAdvpixelLoading(true)

    let count = 0

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      count++
      setportalDboAdvpixelCount(count)
    }, 1000)

    if (token) {
      try {
        await fetch(
          `//${
            import.meta.env.VITE_BE_HOST
          }/api/portal-dbo-advpixel?token=${token}`,
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            setportalDboAdvpixel(data)
            setportalDboAdvpixelLoading(false)

            // clear timer
            clearInterval(timer)
          })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    } else {
      setportalDboAdvpixelLoading(false)
      popupValidation('error', 'Please enter a segment id')
    }
  }

   const getSegmentDataRace = async (date, token) =>
    await Promise.race([
      getThirdPartyLiveRampSegments(date, token),
      getportalDboAdvpixel(token),
    ])
```

`value` from `queryRace` is undefined...would I have to move all my states etc into the `queryRace` ?

I have removed the value...but still the slower function `getThirdPartyLiveRampSegments` is still running. When the others data has been populated.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a boolean variable in the outer scope that will be checked and set in the each `.then`, and if it's already set, just stop further processing.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

Comment: Thanks @Etheryte I have just implemented it as I think ...but value is undefined...any ideas? 

The functions do run though and complete.

Answer (score 1):

The [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

```js
const segmentData = await Promise.race([getDataOne(), getDataTwo()])
```

---

To stop the execution of the late function, you can use the JavaScript **Promise.race()** method with a state variable, as follows for example:

```js
let state = 'idle'

const getDataOne = async => {
  await fetch('//some-api/one').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    if (state === 'idle') {
      setDataOne(date)
      state = 'success'
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getDataTwo = async => {
  await fetch('//some-api/two').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    if (state === 'idle') {
      setDataTwo(date)
      state = 'success'
    }
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const getSegmentData = async() => await Promise.race([getDataOne(), getDataTwo()])
```

Comment: lovely thanks I used your first example, as the 2nd one wouldn't allow me to access the function names...anyways...the slower function doesnt stop when the faster one resolves. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesnt work. I have used a `useState` but there is nothing in the conditional to use the state once its true / success.

Comment: @mrpbennett, you're not returning anything from the async functions (`getDataOne()` and `getDataTwo()`), so nothing is going to get resolved, your only way to access what the fetch requests gained back from the API is by using the variable which is getting set by the `setDataOne()` or `setDataTwo()` functions.

Comment: @mrpbennett, according to my understanding of your code sample, what you actually want to do is to unify the API response resolved values, in other words, you should save the data in one variable like `data` instead of `data1` + `data2` by a method like `setData()` what you're doing is `setDataOne()` + `setDataTwo()`

Comment: thats because the each data is represented within its own table to be displayed. Therefore needs to be separate